# Replace rewrite output URL aliases

Tags: path-aliases

Is it possible to rewrite parts of taxonomy terms URL custom aliases before output, for example with something similar to the the following code?

```
  function replace_term_url ($term_alias) {
    // Url alias "article/first"
    $term_alias = str_replace("article", "article-sub", $term_alias);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 7 there isn't a specific hook to alter the URL associated with a taxonomy term, but you can use the generic hooks for altering URLs, which are [hook_url_inbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7), and [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7).

```
function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if (preg_match('|^taxonomy/term/([0-9]*)|', $path, $matches)) {
    // Alter $path; $matches[1] contains the term ID.
  }
}

function mymodule_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {
  // Revert the change done in mymodule_url_outbound_alter().
}
```

`hook_url_outbound_alter()` is invoked for URLs output from Drupal, `hook_url_inbound_alter()` is invoked for URLs Drupal is receiving.

In Drupal 6, it is possible to implement [hook_term_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_term_path/6), but that is invoked only for the module associated with the taxonomy term. The code invoking that hook is in [taxonomy_term_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_path/6).

```
  if ($vocabulary->module != 'taxonomy' && $path = module_invoke($vocabulary->module, 'term_path', $term)) {
    return $path;
  }
```

If you want to use a third-party module, then there is the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, which allows to automatically set the alias for users, nodes, and taxonomy terms.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which the administrator can change.

Comment: Hi kiamlaluno, thx for your answer. i know "Pathauto" and url_inbound_alter / url_outbound_alter. But with ...alters it's possible to get an original path ( taxonomy/term/%, etc.) and not alias (category/cars, etc.). I need to replace or delete parts of alias path.

Comment: If you implement both the hooks, so that pathA is replaced with pathB in `hook_url_outbound_alter()`, and pathB is replaced with pathA in `hook_url_inbound_alter()`, then it is like having a path alias. What I reported are the only ways I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module:

You can use it to set up automatic aliases for taxonomy terms, as well as content and other things.